# Hallway light switch makes bedroom light brighter

Tags: switches, diy, home-installation

In an older North American home, when I turn my bedroom light switch on, the ceiling light turns on and seems fine. When I then turn the switch for the hallway light on, then the bedroom light becomes brighter. Is the bedroom light somehow now getting 240v instead of 120v? And what would cause this?

Comment: If it were 240V the light bulb would pop!

Comment: Cross posted here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/201869/97780

Comment: @SolarMike correct; should I delete this EE one then?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, if it was a typical incandescent of fluorescent bulb. But LEDs often have driver circuits that can handle wide ranges - e.g., 100V - 250V.

Comment: @CharlesCowie is there any indication of an open neutral?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact if it were an LED bulb it wouldn't change brightness based on voltage variations.  They are either on or off once you pass the on/off voltage threshold.

Comment: Loose neutral.  Still connected, but not firmly.

Comment: @Aaron: depends on the bulb. some will sample avg voltage through a cap to determine output level, which works with most dimmer circuits (rheo, triac, etc).

Comment: @CharlesCowie, an open neutral means **loss of connection to the center of the split 120-0-120 VAC of the transformer**. This is not uncommon, and it causes the mains to be divided unevenly across each side. Putting a load on one circuit causes an increase in voltage on the opposite circuit. This is dangerous and requires immediate attention!

Comment: Do what the Dr says and inspect Neutral voltage to gnd on each condition and hunt for a bad connection at end or another.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a multiwire branch circuit (also called shared neutral). Instead of running two separate cables from Phase A and Phase B at the panel to the branch circuits, the electrician runs a single 3-wire cable carrying Phase A Hot, Phase B hot, and Neutral (shared) to power two branch circuits. Saves a cable run, and therefore labor and copper costs.

The downside is that if the loads are unbalanced on these two branches, there can be enough voltage drop in the neutral conductor to cause slightly unbalanced voltages at your devices. Perhaps that's why the bedroom light brightens when the hallway light comes on. But it should take a bigger unbalance than that, so I suspect you may have a corroding connection in the neutral line somewhere. Get a voltmeter and do some testing.

Comment: No the legs are 180 out of phase and have no affect on each other  for a mwbc